# How to use aes-encryption in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, functions, encryption, postgresql-9.1

I tried aes-encryption by using following statement:

```
SELECT encrypt('test', 'key', 'aes');
```

which worked, but I am not able to decrypt the value. I inserted it in a field of datatype **bytea** but I'm not sure if that was the right way.

```
SELECT decrypt(pw, 'key', 'aes') FROM table WHERE ID = 1;
```

gives me the error

> ERROR:  function decrypt(bytea, unknown, unknown) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT decrypt(pw, 'key', 'aes') FROM tabelle WHERE ID = 7;
>                  ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Does that really mean that encrypt() is an existing function, but not decrypt()? How else could I retreive aes-encrypted values?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`\df *crypt` in psql reveals the argument types of the pgcrypto `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions ([as do the PgCrypto docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html)):

```
                                List of functions
 Schema |      Name       | Result data type |   Argument data types    |  Type  
--------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------
 ...
 public | decrypt         | bytea            | bytea, bytea, text       | normal
 public | encrypt         | bytea            | bytea, bytea, text       | normal
 ...
```

so both the `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions expect the key to be `bytea`. As per the error message, "you might need to add explicit type casts".

However, it works fine here on Pg 9.1, so I suspect there's more to it than you've shown. Perhaps you have another function also named `encrypt` with three arguments?

Here's how it works on a clean Pg 9.1:

```
regress=# create table demo(pw bytea);
CREATE TABLE
regress=# insert into demo(pw) values ( encrypt( 'data', 'key', 'aes') );
INSERT 0 1
regress=# select decrypt(pw, 'key', 'aes') FROM demo;
  decrypt   
------------
 \x64617461
(1 row)

regress=# select convert_from(decrypt(pw, 'key', 'aes'), 'utf-8') FROM demo;
 convert_from 
--------------
 data
(1 row)
```

### Awooga! Awooga! Key exposure risk, extreme admin caution required!

BTW, please think carefully about whether PgCrypto is really the right choice. Keys in your queries can be revealed in `pg_stat_activity` and the system logs via `log_statement` or via crypto statements that fail with an error. [IMO it's frequently better to do crypto in the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054503/storing-encrypted-data-in-postgres).

Witness this session, with `client_min_messages` enabled so you can see what'd appear in the logs:

```
regress# SET client_min_messages = 'DEBUG'; SET log_statement = 'all'; 
regress=# select decrypt(pw, 'key', 'aes') from demo;
LOG:  statement: select decrypt(pw, 'key', 'aes') from demo;
LOG:  duration: 0.710 ms
  decrypt   
------------
 \x64617461
(1 row)
```

Whoops, key possibly exposed in the logs if `log_min_messages` is low enough. It's now on the server's storage, along with the encrypted data. Fail. Same issue without `log_statement` if an error occurs to cause the statement to get logged, or possibly if `auto_explain` is enabled.

Exposure via `pg_stat_activity` is also possible.. Open two sessions, and:

- S1: `BEGIN;`
- S1: `LOCK TABLE demo;`
- S2: `select decrypt(pw, 'key', 'aes') from demo;`
- S1: `select * from pg_stat_activity where current_query ILIKE '%decrypt%' AND procpid <> pg_backend_pid();`

Whoops! There goes the key again. It can be reproduced without the `LOCK TABLE` by an unprivileged attacker, it's just harder to time it right. The attack via `pg_stat_activity` can be avoided by revoking access to `pg_stat_activity` from `public`, but it just goes to show that it might not be best to send your key to the DB unless you know your app is the only thing ever accessing it. Even then, I don't like to.

### If it's passwords, should you store them at all?

Furthermore, if you're storing passwords, don't two-way encrypt them; if at all possible *salt passwords then hash them and store the result*. You usually don't need to be able to recover the password cleartext, only confirm that the stored hash matches the password the user sends you to log in when it's hashed with the same salt.

### If it's auth, let someone else do it for you

Even better, don't store the password at all, authenticate against LDAP, SASL, Active Directory, an OAuth or OpenID provider, or some other external system that's already designed and working.

### Resources

- [Secure Password authentication explained simply - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54164/Secure-Password-Authentication-Explained-Simply)
- [Wikipedia: Challenge-response authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication)
- [Wikipedia: Cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)
- [Wikipedia: Salt (cryptography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))
- [Wikipedia: Password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password)

and lots more.

Comment: It's not more than I shown, and I didn't define new functions, its a new installed postgresql. It is quite irritating that your sample and the first select-statement I've posted also not work meanwhile, returning the same error as posted above. Somewhere something went wrong...thanks anyhow for your answer.

Comment: Try on a newly `CREATE`d database from `template0`; eg `CREATE DATABASE testdb TEMPLATE template0` then `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;` and test. See if there's something dodgy in template1.

Comment: Just a note regarding two-way decryption in the db.  I don't think it's always the wrong direction but, it adds complexity and anywhere you deal with this you really have to deal with key management which can be more complicated in the db.

Comment: Also 100% second the notion that you should NEVER have to decrypt passwords and that hooking into a system maintained by more people is usually a significant win security-wise.

Comment: @32bitfloat any luck? Don't know if you noticed my earlier comment, I forgot to at-reply you.

Comment: I created a new database as you recommended and it worked perfectly. Many thanks for your help! - I used to encrypt passwords with aes in mysql because it felt more save, but I will rethink that. Thanks for the additional information.

Comment: lol, +1 for "Awooga! Awooga!"

Answer (score 0):

After installing pgcrypto extension, to encrypt in AES-256 use:

```
pgp_sym_encrypt('".$value."', '".$key."', 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256')
```

result field type is bytea. Stored as is in PostgreSQL bytea type field. To decrypt the bytea:

```
pgp_sym_decrypt(your_table.your_bytea_column , '".$key."', 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256')
```

also bytea fields can be encoded/decoded to/from base64 with encode/decode functions;

```
encode(your_table.your_bytea_column, 'base64') //result is string
decode(your_table.your_string_column, 'base64') //result is bytea
```